# Using getItemCount with ListAdapter in Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I am trying to do something pretty simple:

Display only a certain amount of items in recyclerview (lets say 5 only).

As we know, using **ListAdapter** with DiffUtil, you do not need to override *getItemCount()* method.

But I need to display a fixed amount of item, so I did override the method.

```
class AllNewsAdapter : ListAdapter<Article, AllNewsAdapter.AllNewsViewHolder>(AllNewsDiffCallback()) {

 var list: List<Article> = listOf()
 private val limit = 5

   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return if (list.size > limit){
        limit
    } else{
        list.size
    }
 }
}
```

Using this, no item is displayed in recyclerview.

But when I remove the entire *getItemCount()* method, ALL the items get displayed, which I don't want

Oh!, I also tried using:

```
return Math.min(list.size(), 5)
```

but no luck (no item is displayed).

While using *RecyclerView.Adapter<>*, I could do this but it doesn't work with *ListAdapter<>*

Comment: You're "fighting the framework". Either use a regular adapter (and supply/use the DIffUtil internally like ListAdapter does), or transform the data (source) and only pass 5 items to the adapter.submitList(). This seems like a data transformation problem, not a recycler view's adapter problem. In my limited experience, trying to _hack_ the way the RV works often leads to unexpected results (not that I'm "against it" but it's been my experience).

Comment: Agree with @MartinMarconcini, why pass all that unnecessary data to the adapter also? Filter the data, pass it to the adapter and notify it about the changes. This should be the safest way.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your adapter :

```
    override fun submitList(list: MutableList<Article>?) {
    // replace 5 with any number you want
    if(list?.size?:0>5) super.submitList(list?.take(5))
    else super.submitList(list)
    }
```